# How can I write high-speed A/D data to an SD card?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, adc, spi, sd

I want to use a microcontroller and A/D converter to do some high-frequency (~100 kHz) long-term (minimum of five second buffer, looping until triggered) data logging. It looks like a good way to do this is with an SD card. I know there are different ways of accessing an SD card, including directly through SPI. I also believe that one can write to a file system, or directly to the card without a file system. I'm also concerned about writes having to cover entire sectors instead of byte-by-byte, or about writes interfering with continuing A/D operation, but those may not be valid concerns.

Presently I'm using dsPIC 33 chips, giving me instruction rates of ~60 MIPS; I'm willing to change to a different controller family if necessary.

Comment: 100 kHz is not high frequency and five seconds is not long term. The crappiest old SD card running with the normal SPI bus will write your data.

Comment: First check whether or not the writing rate can even theoretically handle your data stream. Then check what is the maximum RAM buffer you can use in order to write it in bursts. Then I would look how can I offload these bursts to the asynchronous DMA..

Comment: 5seconds * 100kHz * 2 (<-nyquist) = 1Mega Sample memory depth. 8bit? Get more than 1M RAM. 16bit? Get more than 2M RAM, etc. Why more than? Stack and general memory use. Never use flash for running buffers, circular buffers, etc. Why? Write endurance -> 10000~50000 times sounds like a lot, but continuously running at 100kHz also generates a lot. Takes less than a week full time to completely wear out a new flash drive if you're not careful.

Comment: How much data do you need to log at 100 kHz?  1 byte? 2 bytes? 4 bytes? 1024 bytes?

Comment: Just A/D converter results, so two bytes max.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not be able to do this with a PIC33, and almost certainly not just any PIC33. Some flash cards 'go away' for long periods of time (tens of milliseconds or more) despite the high throughput this latency can kill you with a small microcontroller because you'll run out of buffer RAM.

If you allow buffering for 200ms (which should be safe) then you will need 20K words of memory, which a PIC33 may not have (the biggest members of the family have 48K x 8, so if your ADC takes two bytes that's 40K, and presumably your program needs some RAM.

At 100,000 samples/second you also won't be able to do much processing on the data, just grab it. I'd suggest using RAM. And you'd have processing power to spare if you used an ARM with an external SDRAM or even serial RAM.

Comment: I agree - the latency of SD cards, even the high-speed ones, is terrible. The high-throughput ones for cameras work best, but only if you can write in large blocks.

Comment: Hmm, quite right.. I think SDHC maximum busy time is 250 ms as per spec (although I've seen 500 ms) and SDXC maximum busy time is 500 ms. I was a member of the SD card association years ago, so I've read the SDHC specs but not the SDXC specs...

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before, but I don't remember the all details. I used Fat filesytem and there was some kind of different approach, I used to transfer a block of data 512 bytes. But I can tell you what you need for sure: a circular buffer, mine was 16k bytes. When you sample in ISR you write into a buffer then you increment write pointer, when the difference between wr and rd pointer exceeds 512 bytes you write those bytes onto a SD and increment rd pointer. Anyway this is old, without use of DMA transfer, just an example. When creating the curcular buffer, do use the size of buffer with power of 2, look for math used with rd and wr pointers, it is simplifed thanks to the property of binary numbers rollover, at any calculation you need to apply mask: & (size-1) whicjh is 2^N-1, in my case N=14 -> size of circ buffer=2^14=16384.

```
void AddBuffer (char data) 
{
    CircBuffer[WR_Pointer]=data;
    WR_Pointer++;
    WR_Pointer= WR_Pointer & 16383;
    if (WR_Pointer==RD_Pointer)
    {
          printf("\r\nBuffer overrun\r\n",0);
          stat0_off();
          stat1_on();
          VICIntEnClr = 0xFFFFFFFF;  //clear all interrupts
          fat_flush();
          while(1);
    }
}

char GetBuffer() 
{
  char res;

  if (WR_Pointer==RD_Pointer)
  {
    res=0; // no data available
    printf("\r\nError calling GetBuffer()\r\n",0);
    stat0_off();
    stat1_on();
    VICIntEnClr = 0xFFFFFFFF;  //clear all interrupts
    fat_flush();
    while(1);

  }
  else
  {
    res=CircBuffer[RD_Pointer];
    RD_Pointer++;
    RD_Pointer=RD_Pointer & 16383; 
  }
  return(res);
}

void SD_Card_Log(void)
{
    int j;        
        BufferLength  = WR_Pointer-RD_Pointer;
        BufferLength = BufferLength & 16383;

        if  (BufferLength>=512)                
        {
          for (j = 0; j < 512; j++)          {           
            RX_array1[j] = GetBuffer();        
          } 

          stat0_off();
          stat1_off();

          if (fat_write(handle,RX_array1, 512) < 0)
          {
                while(1) // card failure
                {
                }
          }
```